# Content filter won't work

Tags: php, functions, filters

I'm trying to filter my content and on matches on flow I would like to change my html structure, but my rule doesn't really apply. I have the following filter which searches the first image of posts and on rule match attaching a css container. The `preg_match_all` is working but the `str_replace` doesn't

```
function imageFooter($content){

      global $post, $posts;

      preg_match_all('/<a.href="(.*?)"><img.*?src="(.*?)".*?><\/a>/', $post->post_content, $matches);
      $to_search = $matches[0][0];
      $replacement = '<div class="image_footer">'.$matches[0][0].'<span class="logo"></span></div>';
      str_replace($to_search , $replacement, $post->post_content);
      return $content;

    }

    add_filter('the_content',   'imageFooter');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change,

```
str_replace($to_search , $replacement, $post->post_content);
```

to..

```
$content =  str_replace($to_search , $replacement, $post->post_content);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was an ordinary big mistake what I made

Comment: No problem, also you are passing $content variable to your function by reference so you don't technically need your globals, you can of course just use $content.

Comment: Yes I have been changing theme as @s_ha_dum suggested

Comment: Good stuff.. all the best.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't set `$content` to anything so it is just returning the same thing that was passed into the function. Read the doc's for [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). You should have:

```
$content = str_replace($to_search , $replacement, $post->post_content);
```

But why are you operating on `$post->post_content`? The post content is passed into the filter. You even have a parameter named `$content` that you aren't using. What you are doing is likely to cause trouble. Think about this.

Your site has 4 filters on `the_content` including yours.

1. Uses `$content`
2. Uses `$content` as modified by filter one, since they "chain".
3. Uses `$content` as modified by the previous two filters.
4. Your filter uses `$post->content` which is outside of the "chain". You've just wiped out all the preceding filters.

Also, you aren't using `$posts` at all.

Your code should be:

```
function imageFooter($content){
      preg_match_all('/<a.href="(.*?)"><img.*?src="(.*?)".*?><\/a>/', $content, $matches);
      $to_search = $matches[0][0];
      $replacement = '<div class="image_footer">'.$matches[0][0].'<span class="logo"></span></div>';
      $content = str_replace($to_search , $replacement, $content);
      return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content',   'imageFooter');
```

And you should be warned that using regex to parser HTML is very dicey business. It is easy to go wrong.